# How to get cookies from WKWebView in Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm trying to switch an existing app from UIWebView to WKWebView in Cordova. The cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr plugin is installed for WKWebView.But cookies not getting using this webkit. My problem is how to get all the cookies using this.

https://github.com/oracle/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr